# `WeatherData` doesn't return meaningful result

Tags: curated-data

As of 06 Sep 2017, `WeatherData` seems to be broken: it cannot return any meaningful weather information.

For instance, `WeatherData["Chicago", "Temperature"]` will return `Missing[NotAvailable]`. Such problem also occurs on the WolframCloud.

What is the reason for such issue? Could it be due to insufficient WolframCredit? Or any other explanation?

Comment: [Related Community post.](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1177923)

Comment: It  is not a Cloud Credits issue, as I am experiencing it too and have plenty. I think this should be reported to technical support.

Comment: Thank you all for the clarification. I've reported this to Wolfram and am waiting for their reply.

Comment: Actually it was already broken yesterday (2017-09-05). I have also reported this to Wolfram. If due to our reports or not, it seems to now have been repaired, at least it works again for me...

Comment: looks like currently it doesn't work again. I have meanwhile got the confirmation from support that the problem is known and worked on...

Comment: Same problem on 2021-09-29. I have reported to Wolfram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is difficult, as only WRI can tell you what exactly is wrong when these functions don't work. If you are using a desktop Mathematica version I don't think that Wolfram Credits are even needed to run `WeatherData` or any of the data functions, so I would exclude that as the reason for the problems you have been seeing. Unfortunately as the functionality depends on interaction between your local installation and some services provided by WRI there are plenty possible reasons for such problems.

There could be a problem with their servers, but if you encounter networking problems that would also explain why you can't get data. There have also been reported cases where the data paclet infrastructure of individual installations has been broken. You can find other questions on this site which explain how one can clean up and reset those.

As several users have reported the same problem during the same time period I would guess that this time it has been a (temporary) problem on the server side. It now (about 24h after the first failures) seems to have been repaired. Unfortunately the information we get when errors occure and other possibilities to get information about the server states are quite limited, so we are left with hoping and speculating...