# `WeatherData` regression in data availability

Tags: curated-data

I notice a remarkable regression in data availability of `WeatherData` for multiple sites recently (as of 11 Sep 2017).

As I used the "ZBAA" dataset collected at Beijing capital airport a lot before, I find now the dataset begins at a very recent date of Mar 1st, 2008, which used to be ~1948 (I cannot remember the exact date).

Is there any news about the regression?

Comment: This is possibly the same as [your previous thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155158).

Comment: It seems this function is much less reliable than before.